# ServerSide ajax request with DataTable multifilter on one column

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a DataTable create like that :

```
var ticketDataTable = $("#ticketDataTable").DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: ajaxUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: function(data) {
                data.ticketStatusFilter = ketStatusCheckboxes.filter(':checked')
                    .map(function() { return this.value; }).get()
                    .join(';')
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { 
                 name: "ticket.ticketNumber",
                 data: "0.ticketNumber" 
            },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },        
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { },
            { }
        ],
        bSortCellsTop: true,
        dom: 'rt<lp>',
        order: [[2, "desc"]]    // Sort by descending date
    });
```

I use SumoSelect to create a dropdown list with checkboxes to realize a multifilter.

```
$("table#ticketDataTable thead tr th#multiSelectFilter").find("select").SumoSelect({ selectAll: true });
```

I need to do a multifilter on my 5th column but i don't know how to do it because of the server side parameter (true). And i can't change it.

If you have an idea to solve my problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to solve it.
I put new data in my ajax request. I use it in my server side to do my request. Then i change the data every click on my filter and i relaunch the request.

Works Fine !